# Why is my Laravel Livewire event emission not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple Livewire component that lists users:

```
class UserListComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $listeners = ['refreshComponent' => '$refresh'];

    public $search = '';
    public $orderBy = 'id';
    public $orderAsc = true;
    public $perPage = 10;

    public function render()
    {   
        return view('livewire.admin.user-list-component',[
            'users' => User::search($this->search)
                ->orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->orderAsc ? 'ASC' : 'DESC') 
                ->simplePaginate($this->perPage)
        ]);
    }
}
```

and a component that adds users:

```
public function addUser()
    {   
        // validate data
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        // generate random password
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4);
        $password = bin2hex($bytes);
        
        // create user
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $validatedData['name'],
            'email' => $validatedData['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        // assign user role
        $user->attachRole('user');

        $this->emitTo('UserListComponent', 'refreshComponent');
    }
```

As you can see, at the end of the `addUser()` function I emit an event to the UserListComponent and have a listener set up in that component to refresh it, so that when a user is added the list of users automatically updates. However, it doesn't work. If I refresh manually I can see that the user is added to the database and display just fine, but the component refreshing does not happen, and no error is thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `'refreshComponent' => '$refresh'` a valid listener? Shouldn't `'$refresh'` be a callback method that is triggered? https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#event-listeners. Nevermind, my fault, seems to be a "_magic action_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see the best way is to use full class name so instead of:

```
$this->emitTo('UserListComponent', 'refreshComponent');
```

you should use:

```
$this->emitTo(\App\Http\Livewire\UserListComponent:class, 'refreshComponent');
```

(of course update namespace if you have `UserListComponent` in other namespace)

Comment: Well, this works a couple of ways. The full path `App\Http\Livewire\UserlistComponent`, and just the component class `UserListComponent::class` without the path. Anyway, it works, thank you!

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yes, both components are in same namespace then `UserListComponent::class` should be fine too but if they are not you should use full namespace (and of course you can import it)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek can we do this in a blade? If yes, how? `emitTo(\App\Http\Livewire\UserListComponent:class, 'refreshComponent')` Thank you.

Comment: I've got a question going for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76951018/livewire-is-it-possible-to-emit-events-to-a-child-in-the-parallel-component