# Livewire - Is it possible to `emit` events to a child in the parallel component tree

Tags: laravel-livewire

Here is my directory structure

```
- abc.blade.php
- Components
  -- Tables
     --- Table1
     --- Table2
  -- Modals
     --- Modal1
     --- Modal2
```

I am able to emit successfully from `abc.blade` to `Modal2` using

```
window.livewire.emitTo('components.modals.modal2')
```

but not able to figure out how do I emit from `table2.blade` to `Modal2`. How to emit to a component that in nested under another component which is at same level as the parent of the emitting one?

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: What is the result of your `emitTo`? Because if that isn't working, it sounds like it's something else. Have you tried the default debugging steps, such as ensuring your `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts`?

Comment: @Yinci sorry I don't understand your comment... I don't even know how to emit to `Modal1` component from `Table1` component. Or do you mean `window.livewire.emitTo('components.modals.modal2')` would work from any component no matter how deep it itself is?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. `emitTo` is an emit directly to the component. Check the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#scope-by-name)

Comment: @Yinci in that case it is not working in my case... the page has a Livewire table which works fine (that answers your question about `livewirestyles & livewirescripts`). And the `emitto` works from `abc.blade` like i said above. It just doesn't work from the nested component.

Comment: For anyone who is looking at this page in future. `window.livewire.emitTo('components.modals.modal2')` would work from any component. There was an issue with my setup where the `modal2` was not present and therefore the emit was not working. Also, thanks for the help @Yinci